# How to modify a legend title in a barplot with ggplot

Tags: r, text, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend

Imagine you have a simple dataset like this one:

```
   ive
      region   Edad
  1  Española   23
  2  Española   37
  3  Española   40
  4  Española   21
  5  Africana   29
  6  Española   42
  7   Europea   29
  8  Española   25
  9  Española   32
  10 Española   20
```

I am interested on performing a barplot for the variable `region` classifying by colour. So I created the following piece of code:

```
 g1 <- ggplot(ive, aes(x=reorder(ive$region, -table(ive$region)[ive$region])))
 g1 + geom_bar(aes(fill=ive$region)) + geom_text(stat='count',aes(label=..count..),vjust=-0.7) + xlab("")
```

But the legend of the plot displays `ive$region` and I want it to display a customized title.

I am almost sure it is a silly question but I have been traying to solve it for 2 days and I dont find the way to do it.

Thank you,
Álvaro

Comment: So `labs(fill = "This is my custom title")`. Also, don't use `$` inside `aes()`.

Comment: `+scale_fill_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title = "Your title"))` should work as well.

Comment: @Haboryme Or just `+scale_fill_discrete(name = "Your title")`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ggplot(ive, aes(x=reorder(ive$region, -table(ive$region)[ive$region]))) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=ive$region)) + 
  geom_text(stat='count',aes(label=..count..),vjust=-0.7) +
  labs(x = "", fill = "Region")
```

[image]

Comment: [The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)

Comment: @Axeman.  Thanks for the cite.  I think you are saying I should have directed the OP to a post that answers his question rather than putting in this answer.  Point taken.